# angular2 Promise issue

Tags: javascript, angular, promise

I'm facing problem when catching the error from the API. As you can see below, I'm calling deletedJob method when clicks on delete button and that function call 'deleteJob' function of jobService.

In Component

```
deleteJob(id) {
   this.jobService.deleteJob(id, this.shopId)
        .then(res => {
          console.log('response');
          // Displaying the success message         
        })
        .catch(this.handleError)
      }
    });
  }
```

deletedJob function in jobService component

```
 deleteJob(id: number, shopId: number) {
    let url = this.jobsUrl() + `/${id}.json`;
    return this.http
      .delete(url)
      .toPromise()
      .then(res => res.json().response)
      .catch(this.handleError);
  }
```

handleError function for above function

```
 handleError(error: any) {
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
  }
```

So when rejecting that error through handleError function, I'm getting an error in console '**TypeError: You provided 'undefined' where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.**'

Comment: What exactly are you doing here? res.json().response

Comment: In the component one, probably you need to return the promise.

Comment: @masterfan you can assume 'res.json()' return an object i.e  {response: 'aa'}. The problem is that when we call deleteJob method, Server gives an error and response goes to the catch block of service.

Comment: you are not returning any parameter while calling `handleError` ?